# eglDestroyContext and unfinished drawcalls

Tags: opengl-es

Following scenario:

I have an OpenGL ES app that renders frames via drawcalls, the end of a frame is marked by eglSwapBuffers. Now imagine that after the last eglSwapBuffers I immediately call eglMakeCurrent to unbind the context from the surface, then immediately call eglDestroyContext. Assuming the context was the last one to hold references to any resources the drawcalls use (shader, buffer, textures etc.) what happens to the drawcalls that the gpu has not yet finished and that use some of these resources?

Regards.

Comment: OpenGL ES doesn't have such a thing as "creating drawcalls"...?

Comment: @user253751 By create I mean calling glDrawArrays/glDrawIndexed etc.  .

Comment: OpenGL ES is supposed to do the things you ask in the order you ask. It can delay them but that is supposed to be invisible to you. It needs to act like it is not delaying them.

Comment: According to https://registry.khronos.org/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglDestroyContext.xhtml a context is destroyed immediately when it is not current anymore. What happens to pending drawcalls that use resources this context held?

Comment: glDrawArrays/etc is also immediate according to the documentation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> then immediately call `eglDestroyContext()`.

All this really says is that the application is done with the context, and promises not to use it again. The actual context includes a reference count held by the graphics driver, and that won't drop to zero until all pending rendering has actually completed.

TLDR - despite what the APIs say, nothing actually happens "immediately" when you make an API call - it's an elaborate illusion that is mostly a complete lie.